How to use query with quotes inside a parent query
I have a use case, where I need to update column value which is itself a query.
Table structure:
CREATE TABLE MyTable 
(
    ID int,
    Query varchar(max)
)

Update query:
UPDATE MyTable  
SET Query = '{{child query}}' 
WHERE ID = @ID;

Child query:
DECLARE @ServiceIDsTableString AS varchar(20)  
SET @ServiceIDsTableString = @ServiceIDsString    

DECLARE @ServiceIDs TABLE (ServiceID INT PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED)    
DECLARE @OrderID varchar(10), @Pos int    

SET @ServiceIDsTableString = LTRIM(RTRIM(@ServiceIDsTableString)) + ',' 
SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(',', @ServiceIDsTableString, 1)    

IF REPLACE(@ServiceIDsTableString, ',', '') <> ''  
BEGIN   
    WHILE @Pos > 0   
    BEGIN    
        SET @OrderID = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@ServiceIDsTableString, @Pos - 1))) 

        IF @OrderID <> ''    
        BEGIN     
            INSERT INTO @ServiceIDs (ServiceID) 
            VALUES (CAST(@OrderID AS int))     
        END    

        SET @ServiceIDsTableString = RIGHT(@ServiceIDsTableString, LEN(@ServiceIDsTableString) - @Pos)    
        SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(',', @ServiceIDsTableString, 1)   
    END  
END       

DECLARE @CurrentTime_UTC AS DateTime    
SELECT @CurrentTime_UTC = GETUTCDATE()      

DECLARE @ProviderTripIDs TABLE (ProviderTripID varchar(255))

INSERT INTO @ProviderTripIDs   
    SELECT ProviderTripID         
    FROM MfTrips mt WITH (nolock)   
    INNER JOIN Mfs m WITH (nolock) ON m.MfID = mt.MfID   
    INNER JOIN MfDatas md WITH (nolock) ON md.MfDataID = m.MfDataID   
    INNER JOIN locations lp WITH (nolock) ON mt.PickLocationID = lp.LocationID   
    INNER JOIN Locations ld WITH (nolock) ON mt.DropLocationID = ld.LocationID   
    INNER JOIN Customers c WITH (nolock) ON mt.CustomerID = c.CustomerID   
    INNER JOIN Reservations r WITH (nolock) ON r.ReservationID = mt.ReservationID  
    WHERE 
        m.active = 1    
        AND r.ParentReservationID = 0   
        AND m.date = @Date     
        AND mt.ProviderID = 1    
        AND mt.MfTripStatusID = 1    
        AND mt.ModeID = 3   
        AND mt.PassengerTypeID IN (SELECT PassengerTypeID 
                                   FROM PassengerTypes WITH (nolock) 
                                   WHERE CorePassengerTypeID = 1)     
        AND mt.ServiceID IN (SELECT ServiceID FROM @ServiceIDs)   
        AND md.MfDataTypeID = dbo.GetCurrentMfDataTypeID(m.Date)    
        AND (mt.WillCall = 0 OR mt.WillCallReadyAt >= '1/1/2000')    
        AND m.description = 'Unassigned'    
        AND mt.LevelOfServiceID = 1    
        AND mt.TripPurposeID NOT IN (1)   
        AND dbo.GetAge(c.BirthDate, m.Date) < 75    
        AND (dbo.GetAge(c.BirthDate, m.Date) > 18 or 
              1 = (SELECT TOP 1 1 
                   FROM MfTripExtraPassengers imtep WITH (nolock)  
                   WHERE imtep.MfTripID = mt.MfTripID 
                     AND imtep.Deleted_UTC IS NULL
                     AND dbo.GetAge(imtep.BirthDate, m.Date) > 18))
       AND (SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM MfTripExtraPassengers imtep WITH (nolock) 
            WHERE imtep.MfTripID = mt.MfTripID 
              AND imtep.Deleted_UTC IS NULL) <= 2   
       AND (SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM MfTripExtraPassengers imtep WITH (nolock) 
            WHERE imtep.MfTripID = mt.MfTripID 
              AND imtep.Deleted_UTC IS NULL
              AND mt.PassengerTypeID NOT IN (SELECT PassengerTypeID 
                                             FROM PassengerTypes WITH (nolock)
                                             WHERE CorePassengerTypeID = 1)) <=0    
       AND mt.C_EstMeters < 48280   
       AND mt.CustomerID NOT IN (SELECT CustomerID 
                                 FROM CustomerProviderExclusions 
                                 WHERE ProviderID = 112 
                                   AND Exclude = 1 
                                   AND RemovedAt_UTC IS NULL)      
       AND (mt.CustomerID IN (SELECT CustomerID 
                              FROM CustomerProviderExclusions 
                              WHERE ProviderID = 112 
                                AND Include = 1 
                                AND RemovedAt_UTC IS NULL
                                AND CustomerID = mt.CustomerID)    
        OR mt.CustomerID NOT IN (SELECT CustomerID 
                 from CustomerProviderExclusions where  Include = 1 and RemovedAt_UTC is null and CustomerID = mt.CustomerID)    )    and         case      when mt.ScheduledPickWindowBegin > m.Date then  mt.ScheduledPickWindowBegin AT TIME ZONE (select Value from ClientSettings where ClientSettingID = 22)     when mt.scheduledDropWindowEnd <CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), DateAdd(dd,2,m.Date), 126)  then       case        when DateAdd(mi,-60,mt.scheduledDropWindowEnd) < DateAdd(ss,-1* ISNULL(mt.C_EstSeconds,0), mt.ScheduledDropWindowEnd) then DateAdd(mi,-60,mt.scheduledDropWindowEnd AT TIME ZONE (select Value from ClientSettings where ClientSettingID = 22))       else DateAdd(ss,-1* ISNULL(mt.C_EstSeconds,0), mt.ScheduledDropWindowEnd AT TIME ZONE (select Value from ClientSettings where ClientSettingID = 22))  end     else     m.Date AT TIME ZONE (select Value from ClientSettings where ClientSettingID = 22)    end          > DateAdd(mi,90,GetUTCDate())         update @ProviderTripIDs set ProviderTripID = SUBSTRING(ProviderTripID,0,11)    select   PickLatitude,   PickLongitude,   PickAdress,   DropLatitude,   DropLongitude,   DropAdress,   CustomerFirstName,   CustomerLastName,   '+'+Replace(Replace(Phone,'-',''),'+','') as [Phone],   CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30),[ScheduledPickTime], 126) as [ScheduledPickTime_ISO8601],   ProviderTripID  from  (  SELECT               cast(Round(lp.Latitude,7,1) as decimal(18,7)) as [PickLatitude]        ,cast(Round(lp.Longitude,7,1) as decimal(18,7)) as [PickLongitude]        ,RTrim(lp.Address1 + ' ' + lp.Address2) + ', ' + lp.City +', ' + lp.State+' ' + lp.Zip as [PickAdress]        ,cast(Round(ld.Latitude,7,1) as decimal(18,7)) as [DropLatitude]      ,cast(Round(ld.Longitude,7,1) as decimal(18,7)) as [DropLongitude]      ,RTrim(ld.Address1 + ' ' + ld.Address2) + ', ' + ld.City +', ' + ld.State+' ' + ld.Zip as [DropAdress]            ,c.FirstName as [CustomerFirstName]      ,c.LastName as [CustomerLastName]      ,ISNULL(        (         SELECT TOP 1 '1'+cc.Description         FROM CustomerContacts cc WITH(NOLOCK)         WHERE cc.Active = 1          AND cc.[Order] = 1          AND cc.CustomerID = mt.CustomerID       and lTrim(rTrim(cc.Description)) <> ''         ),          isnull(      ( SELECT TOP 1 '1'+cc.Description         FROM CustomerContacts cc WITH(NOLOCK)         WHERE cc.Active = 1          AND cc.CustomerID = mt.CustomerID            and lTrim(rTrim(cc.Description)) <> ''       order by [Order])      ,'19999999999')            ) as [Phone]      ,case      when mt.ScheduledPickWindowBegin > m.Date then  mt.ScheduledPickWindowBegin AT TIME ZONE (select Value from ClientSettings where ClientSettingID = 22)     when mt.scheduledDropWindowEnd <CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), DateAdd(dd,2,m.Date), 126)  then       case        when DateAdd(mi,-60,mt.scheduledDropWindowEnd) < DateAdd(ss,-1* ISNULL(mt.C_EstSeconds,0), mt.ScheduledDropWindowEnd) then DateAdd(mi,-60,mt.scheduledDropWindowEnd AT TIME ZONE (select Value from ClientSettings where ClientSettingID = 22))       else DateAdd(ss,-1* ISNULL(mt.C_EstSeconds,0), mt.ScheduledDropWindowEnd AT TIME ZONE (select Value from ClientSettings where ClientSettingID = 22))  end     else     m.Date AT TIME ZONE (select Value from ClientSettings where ClientSettingID = 22)    end           as [ScheduledPickTime],     mt.ProviderTripID            FROM  MfTrips mt with (nolock)   INNER JOIN Mfs m  with (nolock)on m.MfID = mt.MfID   inner join MfDatas md with (nolock) on md.MfDataID = m.MfDataID   inner join locations lp with (nolock) on mt.PickLocationID = lp.LocationID   inner join Locations ld with (nolock) on mt.DropLocationID = ld.LocationID   inner join Customers c  with (nolock)on mt.CustomerID = c.CustomerID   inner join Reservations r with (nolock) on mt.ReservationID = r.ReservationID      where   m.active = 1    and m.date = @Date     and mt.ProviderID = 1    and mt.MfTripStatusID = 1    and mt.ModeID = 3   and substring(mt.ProviderTripID,0,11) in (Select ProviderTripID from @ProviderTripIDs)   and md.MfDataTypeID = dbo.GetCurrentMfDataTypeID(m.Date)       )a     order by ProviderTripID

The child query is a long complex query and has multiple quotes in it.
These child queries are being prepared in SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) for generating the reports later.
What I am doing is to use Replace function of C# and replace all single quotes with '' of the child query and then use it in the parent query.
But I need to make sure that the replace operation doesn't mess with the original child query.
Is there any better way to perform this operation?

You've not given details of where the child query comes from...However, you need to make sure the child query is valid Sql and then insert it into the parent query. Without more details, it will be hard to give more information. But the usual caveats of Sql injection and parameters always apply

Please [edit] the question and show us the C# code that you tried. Also, do you want to store the text of the SQL query or the result of running the SQL query?

Use parameters. UPDATE MyTable       SET Query = @query      WHERE ID = @ID and set the value of the query parameter to the  query text as per what you pasted here

Please don't put large amounts of code on a single line...  Reformat if to be readable.

You can't run that child query within an update statement anyway? You'd have to run it prior, and then use a variable in the update. So you have a far bigger problem than worrying about quotes.

With SQLParameters and friends it's trivial to write and execute your query, no need to mess with anything. If you writing raw queries, then yeah, it becomes a hassle, but there's no reason for it

Your post is not clear on your intent. My best interpretation is that (1) You have complete queries stored as text in a table. (2) You need to make (minor?) changes to that query. (3) To do this, you want to script out the current query value as an UPDATE script, where the current value is a string in the SET clause. (4) If executed unchanged, the generated script would just the the query back to the current value. (5) You intend to make (minor?) changes to that query and use the generated script to apply those changes back to the database. - Is this close?

Ok.  There's a native way to store a bunch of TSQL statements in the database and execute them later.  It's called a "Stored Procedure", and you can learn about them on the internet: Create a stored procedure

Its a two sided thing. Sure you have your query centrally stored, but when you update it the update of the query and the update of the client software have to be simultaneously, if the structure of the exchanged data changes and the old clients software cannot be used anymore.
I had to deal with such a configuration and for me there were way more downsides to it, when storing queries and procedures in the server.

Not really.  It's just stored code either way, and has all the same deployment concerns.
